# Where to store the callout-line-style.xml

Tags: qgis-3

Where to store the callout-line-style.xml created by @underdark in QGIS?
https://anitagraser.com/2021/07/28/great-label-callout-lines/

It can be imported with the stylemanager (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/style_manager.html), where can I find it on my Windows PC?

Answer (score 0):

The style manager is accessed from QGIS (as explained in the link you provide it's in the setting menu or by a button on the Project toolbar).

For the XML style file you don't need to store it in a particular place, you will need it only once for loading the symbols in QGIS. After you have imported the symbols with the style manager you can delete it from your computer the symbols will still be available (you could keep it in case you have to reinstall QGIS and don't want to download it again but that's up to you)